# Can dp be applied to TextView autosize?

Tags: android, text, textview, size, autosize

```
autoSizeTextType="uniform"
autoSizeMinTextSize="12dp"
autoSizeMaxTextSize="36dp"
autoSizeStepGranularity="3dp"
```

I know that sp is more appropriate, but can't units like dp or px apply?

Answer (score 0):

There's now an official solution to this problem. Autosizing TextViews introduced with Android O are available in the Support Library 26 and is backwards compatible all the way down to Android 4.0.

https://developer.android.com/preview/features/autosizing-textview.html